# How to detect if user has ActiveX filtering?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, activex

I am detecting if the user has Flash installed, but it doesn't detect if ActiveX Filtering is on in IE, which blocks Flash player.

How can I detect if Flash is enabled as well as installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do it in a Flash app. Nevertheless, JavaScript can be useful for this task. Here is Active-X detection [example](http://www.webmaster-forums.net/html-css-and-javascript/activex-detection-possible).